# how to use jquery ajax validation using remote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a program in jsp to check whether an email address exist in database or not , if it exist it will give me "1" and if it does not exist it will give me default as "0" , which is working perfectly

Now i want to call this url in my jquery and validate my email address , i have written some code in jquery but it is not working , my error message for email is working but for remote is not working. Please need some help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#user_form").validate({
        rules: {
            phone: {
                required: "true",
                minlength: "10"
            },
            email: {
                required: "true",
                email: "true",
                remote: {
                    url: 'validate_emailid_succes.jsp',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        email: function () {
                            return $("#email").val()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                remote: jQuery.validator.format("Email ID is already taken")
            },
            phone: "Please enter a 10 digit mobile number"
        }
    });
});
```

Need some guidance so that i can understand where i am going wrong.
Thank You